# Is it possbile to call android spinner from a click of ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I have an image button which says **Select city** I want to call an android spinner if anyone clicks on that image. Is it possible??

Comment: What do you mean by "call a android spinner"? Displaying a dialog with a spinner containing a list of cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you check out the App/Alert Dialogs section of the API Demos application.  I think what you are looking for is a dialog with a single choice list.

Or take a look at this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible in several ways. One way is to have a spinner whose visibility is GONE. Clicking on the image makes the spinners visibility VISIBLE. 
Another choice is to create a dialog that has the spinner and use the selection to do whatever it is you want to do.

There are other options, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mySpinner.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please take a minute to explain what your code does and how it answers the OP's question.